# Output two digits after decimal separator

Tags: c++, c, printf

Using fprintf, what is the format-string to output two digits after a decimal separator?

```
float number = 3.0;
fprintf(pFile, "%10.02f", number);
```

This always outputs 3 instead of 3.00

How do I fill up the digits after decimal separator with zeros? I want 3.00 written in the output file.

Comment: Incidentally, your example code does produce 3.00 as its output.

Comment: Oh crap, it's Excel who does remove the .00 (save as csv) ... sorry

Answer (score 5):

Use `%.2f` as your format specifier instead, or if you want 10 spaces first `%10.2f`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to represent currency amounts. Please don't use floats for this purpose. Decimal numbers aren't represented exactly with floats, this can lead to roundoff errors you don't want.